# Find the two most recent dates for each customer in Python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with purchase date of of each customer. I want to find out most recent purchase date and second most recent purchase date of each unique customer. Here is my dataframe:

```
   name    date
    ab1     6/1/18
    ab1     6/2/18
    ab1     6/3/18
    ab1     6/4/18
    ab2     6/8/18
    ab2     6/9/18
    ab3     6/23/18
```

I am expecting the following output:

```
name    second most recent date        most recent date
ab1      6/3/18                         6/4/18
ab2      6/8/18                         6/9/18
ab3      6/23/18                        6/23/18
```

I know `data['date'].max()` can give the most recent purchase date but I don't have any idea how I can find the second most recent date. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the two most recent purchase date for each customer, you can first sort your dataframe in descending order by date, then groupby the name and convert the aggregated dates into individual columns. Finally just take the first two of these columns and you'll have just the two most recent purchase dates for each customer.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

# set up data from your example
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "name": ["ab1", "ab1", "ab1", "ab1", "ab2", "ab2", "ab3"],
    "date": ["6/1/18", "6/2/18", "6/3/18", "6/4/18", "6/8/18", "6/9/18", "6/23/18"]
})

# create column of datetimes (for sorting reverse-chronologically)
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

# group by name and convert dates into individual columns
grouped_df = df.sort_values(
    "datetime", ascending=False
).groupby("name")["date"].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
# truncate and rename columns
grouped_df = grouped_df[["name", 0, 1]]
grouped_df.columns = ["name", "most_recent", "second_most_recent"]
```

With `grouped_df` like this at the end:

```
  name most_recent second_most_recent
0  ab1      6/4/18             6/3/18
1  ab2      6/9/18             6/8/18
2  ab3     6/23/18                NaN
```

If you want to fill any missing `second_most_recent` values with the corresponding `most_recent` value, you can use `np.where`. Like this:

```
import numpy as np

grouped_df["second_most_recent"] = np.where(
    grouped_df.second_most_recent.isna(),
    grouped_df.most_recent,
    grouped_df.second_most_recent
)
```

With result:

```
  name most_recent second_most_recent
0  ab1      6/4/18             6/3/18
1  ab2      6/9/18             6/8/18
2  ab3     6/23/18            6/23/18
```